# AngularJS Binding Text to Scope Variable

Tags: angularjs

I have a text field that is being controlled by jQuery/external Javascript. I'm looking to add something that causes the text field to also be shown on another element. I'm looking to develop something like this but I know this isn't how you program it:

```
<span id="reading" ng-bind="reading"></span>
<div ng-bind="reading"></div>
<script>
$('#reading').text('100');
</script>
```

The desired output is to have 100 displayed in both the span and the div.

Answer (score 1):

So rather that going for `jQuery` method to change the text, I'd change the `reading` scope value.

```
$scope.reading = '10'
```

But I know you wanted to call that method from external context of angular, so below is the way by which you could access the scope by having DOM query on `ng-controller` name .

```
var scope = angular.element('[ng-controller=ctrl]').scope();
scope.reading = '10'
scope.$apply(); // to update bindings.
```

Comment: I like it. Is also works for dynamic controllers? routes for example?

Comment: @Dvir if you pass the `controller name` dynamically to this method then it could work..

Comment: Hi.. I already have existing code that is not AngularJS -- a lot of it. I'm trying to use AngularJS to avoid using more of the old code

Comment: Is there anyway to watch the .text() of #reading with simple AngularJS directives?

Comment: @PankajParkar But what happens if you set a route config with controller. There is no element `ng-controller` on the page (In the DOM).

Comment: @user2476265 You should avoid jQuery to manipulate the element for your case. As Pankaj said you have to access angular by angular jQlite and manipulate the scope. you can set watch on the reading property.

Comment: @Dvir if its `ngRoute` router in app then he could use `angular.element('[ng-view]').scope()` there in a place..

Comment: I can't avoid using jQuery... the code I placed in there is just an example - in reality there are 600 lines of code and I just want to use AngularJS to watch this one particular part inside a much bigger project

Comment: @Dvir I understand your concern, he shouldn't manipulate angular` scope ` from jQuery.. but sometimes in actual world it happens..like you are migrating very big application to `Angular` from `jQuery` then its normal case which I could think of..

Answer (score 0):

If you want angular to detect your changes. you should do that in $apply(). You have to create a directive on those elements. inside that directive write a link function

```
link:function(scope,ele,attrs,ngModel){

      scope.$apply(update);  //trigger digest cycle 

        function update() {
              ngModel.$setViewValue(100); //changes model
              ngModel.$render();  //updates view
        }
}
```

Comment: is there anyway of doing this without adding a new directive?

I was hoping I could do something using HTML directives

Comment: It's not about directive. the script which is going to change the value should be inside $apply(). otherwise angular wont detect the change

Comment: so AngularJS can not detect DOM changes made by jQuery?

Comment: May be you are using angularJs for some parts of your application. once you pick up angularJs, better stick with that. forget Jquery way of manipulating data and DOM

Comment: It is recommended that DOM changes should be made only in directives

Comment: okay.. I have an existing jQuery project that I know nothing about and I was interested in adding AngularJS to handle data binding between different elements